# Dynamic Allocation for a Struct with template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a code, which is an implementation of doubly linked list.

```
template<class T>
struct Node{
    T value;
    struct Node * next_;
    struct Node * prev_;
};

template <class T>
class Dex
{
  public:
    struct Node<T> * head = (struct Node<T> *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node<T>));
    struct Node<T> * tail = (struct Node<T> *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node<T>));
    struct Node<T> * current = (struct Node<T> *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node<T>));
```

When I compile this, I receive the following error:

> [Error] there are no arguments to 'calloc' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'calloc' must be available [-fpermissive]

I've tried malloc, new etc. But I want to stick to calloc() for this one. Any other method to allocate memory is appreciated, as long as it works and won't throw any SIGSEV.

I expect the code to compile successfully, and be able to initialize a     (struct Node *) pointer without having to deal with memory problems.

Comment: #include <stdlib.h> ?

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a `#include <cstdlib>` ? Also since you don't want to have to deal with memory problems it might be an idea to look for existing, tested implementations like `std::list` ?

Comment: `#include<cstdlib>` works fine, but since this code is in a *.h* file, I'd stick with `new Node<T>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're just missing the needed include:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

However, you can use `new` for this. There's virtually no reason to use `calloc()` in C++. To default-initialize when allocating with `new`, use:

```
Node<T> * head = new Node<T>();
Node<T> * tail = new Node<T>();
Node<T> * current = new Node<T>();
```

The `()` at the end will default-initialize the struct members. For built-in types, it zeroes them just like `calloc()` would do.

Off-topic:
You don't need to type `struct` before the struct name in C++. You can change your code to:

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    Node * next_;
    Node * prev_;
};

template <class T>
class Dex {
public:
    Node<T> * head = new Node<T>();
    Node<T> * tail = new Node<T>();
    Node<T> * current = new Node<T>();
```